# spring mvc. POST form doesn't bind

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have some simple class Man which contain constructors, getters and setters

```
public class Man {

    @Size(min = 3, max = 20, message = "Username must be between 3 and 20 characters long.")
    @Pattern(regexp="^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$", message = "Username must be alphanumeric with no spaces")
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 1, max = 2, message = "Age must be between 1 and 2 characters long")
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]+$", message = "Age must be numerical with no spaces")
    private String age;

    Man(){

    }

    Man(String name, String age){
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public String getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAge(String age){
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

**it service:**

```
@Service
public class ManService {
Map<String, Man> people = new HashMap();
public void saveMan(Man man){
        System.err.println(man); // after the form is submitted object is created
        System.err.println(man.getName()); // but it name == null
        System.err.println(man.getAge()); // and age == null
        people.put(man.getName(), man);
    }

}
```

**common controller.**
When go to /user?new, will be created object Man() and inserted into box modelAttribute, but after the form will be commited, name and age Man() object's fields will be equal null values.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = GET, params = "new")
public String outputParam(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("box",new Man());
    return "param";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = POST)
public String addFromForm(@Valid Man man, BindingResult bindingResult){
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "param";
    }
    manService.saveMan(man);
    return "redirect:../list";
}
```

**view:**

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="box" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <fieldset>
                <table cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th><sf:label path="name">User name:</sf:label></th>
                        <td><sf:input path="name" size="15" /></td>
                        <sf:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th><sf:label path="age">Age:</sf:label></th>
                        <td><sf:input path="age" size="20" /></td> 
                        <sf:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>

                    </tr>
                    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="sent this shit" />
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </sf:form>
```

In result POST form not binding values from input fields.

Comment: And why should it bind? You don't have a `@ModelAttribute` annotation in your post method. Next to that it will bind to a parameters starting with `man.` instead of `box.` due to the naming of your property. Add `@ModelAttribute("box")` next to `@Valid`.

Comment: I added @ModelAttribute("box") next to @Valid but values still equals null.

Comment: Don't post as multipart form or configure multipart support correctly.

Comment: it can work correctly without adding @ModelAttribute("box") next to @Valid

Comment: It can but then you have an object that isn't a form object. Binding works but when you redisplay the page incase you have an error there is no model object anymore. SO basically always use `@ModelAttribute` when you want the results to persist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = POST)
public String addFromForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("box") Man man, BindingResult bindingResult){
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "param";
    }
    manService.saveMan(man);
   return "redirect:../list";
}
```

as suggested by @M. Deinum

While making POST request, you have to encode the data and reques.

HTML forms provide three methods of encoding.

If your form has a file with it, then you have to use multipart/form-data.

I don't think for the normal forms you should be using it. Rather use application/x-www-form-urlencoded (it is in by default).

Comment: Thank you very much, it started work without enctype="multipart/form-data" tag, but why? I read this tutorial in "Spring in action" book. If you can see on page 187 of this book http://unpherum.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/manning-spring-in-action-3rd-edition-jun-2011.pdf there all does correct.

Comment: @user3491167: You can see my updated answer. Sorry but can't see the wordpress site now for confimation.

Comment: it can work correctly without adding @ModelAttribute("box") next to @Valid

Comment: @user3491167: Yes it can. It will work even if you have a plain HTML form if the name of the tag is matching the field name.