# Spring Thymeleaf form POST not sending updated collection model attribute

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot application that server side renders the web pages. One of the forms the application has isn't working correctly. The form will render the page correctly, and will bind the value to the input. When a value is changed, and the form submitted the value received by controller is the original one.

I have a `CardDTO` object, that has the following:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CardDTO {
    private int cardId;
    // Other fields
    private List<CustomValueDTO> customValues;
}
```

That is added to the model as a `card` attribute.

The form is then looks like:

```
<form method="post" action="#" th:action="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}" th:object="${card}">
    <div class="row" th:if="${editType == 'notes'}">
        <div class="col-12 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" type="submit" th:text="#{app.savebtn.label}">SAVE</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:switch="${editType}">
        <!-- other cases -->
        <div th:case="'notes'" th:insert="card-form-section-notes :: notes-form"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>
    <div th:fragment="notes-form" id="notes-edit-form" class="pr-3">
        <div class="row text-left" th:each="i: *{#numbers.sequence(0, customValues.size() - 1)}" th:if="*{customValues}">
            <div th:switch="*{customValues[__${i}__].type.name()}">
                <div th:case="LETTER" class="form-group md-form">
                    <textarea rows="1" type="text"
                        class="form-control custom-textarea"
                        th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}" placeholder="Enter letters only"
                        th:errorclass="invalid"></textarea>
                    <label th:for="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}"></label>
                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('customValues[__${i}__].value')}"
                        th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>
                </div>

                <!-- more inputs -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

With the controller method looking like:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"card"})
public class CardCreateEditController {

    @PostMapping(value = {"/cards/{cardUUID}/{updateType}/edit","/locations/{locationUUID}/cards/{cardUUID}/{updateType}/edit"})
    public String submitChildCardEdit(@AuthenticationPrincipal OidcUser currentUser, @PathVariable String updateType, @PathVariable String cardUUID, @PathVariable Optional<String> locationUUID, @ModelAttribute("card") @Valid final CardDTO editCardDTO, final BindingResult bindingResult, final Model model, final SessionStatus status) {
    // logic here
    }
}
```

So the issue is that when the form is updated, the `@ModelAttribute("card") @Valid final CardDTO editCardDTO` parameter that is sent with it still has the original values in `editCardDTO.customValues(i)` from when the page loaded.

Looking at the network request in Chrome it shows that it's submitting the form being submitted with the update values, and these form parameters:

```
customValues[0].value: database1234
customValues[1].value: test
...
```

I have tried adding all fields from the `CustomValueDTO` as hidden inputs, which are also submitted as form params but still not changes.

This is pretty much the exact same to a different form I have, and that one works perfectly. I can't seem to figure out why this one doesn't.

**UPDATE** - with full HTML:

*card-edit-form.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>

    <div th:fragment="card-form-content">

        <div class="card">

            <!-- Card body -->
            <div class="card-body">

                <p class="h4 mb-3" th:text="#{${'myCompany.header.edit.'+editType}}">EDIT</p>
                <form method="post" action="#" th:action="${#httpServletRequest.requestURI}" th:object="${card}"
                    autocomplete="off" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
                    <div class="row" th:if="${editType == 'notes'}">
                        <div class="col-12 text-right">
                            <a th:if="${locationObj==null}" href="#"
                                th:href="@{/cards/{cardUUID}/cancel(cardUUID=${{cardUUID}})}"
                                th:text="#{myCompany.cancelbtn.label}" tabindex="-1">CANCEL</a>
                            <a th:if="${locationObj!=null}" href="#"
                                th:href="@{/locations/{locationUUID}/cards/{cardUUID}/cancel(cardUUID=${{cardUUID}},locationUUID=${{locationObj.locationUUID}})}"
                                th:text="#{myCompany.cancelbtn.label}" tabindex="-1">CANCEL</a>
                            <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" type="submit" th:text="#{myCompany.savebtn.label}">SAVE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h6 class="mb-4" th:if="${#messages.msgOrNull('myCompany.subheader.edit.'+editType)!=null}"
                        th:text="#{${'myCompany.subheader.edit.'+editType}}">SUBTITLE</h6>
                    <hr>
                    <div th:switch="${editType}">
                        <div th:case="'ico'" th:insert="card-form-section-ico :: ico-form"></div>
                        <div th:case="'info'" th:insert="card-form-section-info :: info-form"></div>
                        <!--/* <div th:case="'address'" th:insert="card-form-section-address :: address-form"></div> */-->
                        <div th:case="'health'" th:insert="card-form-section-health :: health-form"></div>
                        <div th:case="'resideswith'" th:insert="card-form-section-resideswith :: resideswith-form">
                        </div>
                        <div th:case="'notes'" th:insert="card-form-section-notes :: notes-form"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div th:if="${editType != 'notes'}">
                        <div class="row mt-5 align-bottom">
                            <div class="col-12 text-right">
                                <a th:if="${locationObj==null}" href="#"
                                    th:href="@{/cards/{cardUUID}/cancel(cardUUID=${{cardUUID}})}"
                                    th:text="#{myCompany.cancelbtn.label}" tabindex="-1">CANCEL</a>
                                <a th:if="${locationObj!=null}" href="#"
                                    th:href="@{/locations/{locationUUID}/cards/{cardUUID}/cancel(cardUUID=${{cardUUID}},locationUUID=${{locationObj.locationUUID}})}"
                                    th:text="#{myCompany.cancelbtn.label}" tabindex="-1">CANCEL</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4" type="submit"
                                    th:text="#{myCompany.savebtn.label}">SAVE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>

            </div> <!-- card body -->
        </div> <!-- card -->

<div th:if="${editType != 'notes'}">
        <div class="mt-4 text-center">
            <small><a href="#" th:text="#{myCompany.learnmore.part1}" data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#whyWeAskModal">LEARN MORE</a> <span th:text="#{myCompany.learnmore.part2}">ABOUT WHY WE
                    ASK FOR THIS INFO.</span></small>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div th:insert="components/card-why-we-ask-for-info :: why-we-ask-modal"></div>

    </div> <!-- fragment -->

</body>

</html>
```

*card-form-section-notes.html*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<body>
    <div th:fragment="notes-form" id="notes-edit-form" class="pr-3">
        <h4 class="mt-3" th:if="*{customValues == null}" th:text="#{myCompany.section.cards.customfields.edit.noneexistmsg}">NONE EXIST YET.</h4>
        <div class="row text-left" th:each="customValue, itemStat : *{customValues}" th:if="*{customValues}">
            <div th:switch="*{customValues[__${itemStat.index}__].type.name()}">
<!--                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].id}">-->
<!--                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].uuid}">-->
<!--                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].type}">-->
<!--                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">-->
<!--                <input type="hidden" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].customField}">-->

                <div th:case="LETTER" class="form-group md-form">
                    <textarea rows="1" type="text"
                        class="form-control custom-textarea"
                        th:field="*{customValues[__${itemStat.index}__].value}" placeholder="Enter letters only"
                        th:errorclass="invalid"></textarea>
<!--                    <label th:for="*{customValues[__${itemStat.index}__].value}" th:text="*{customValues[__${itemStat.index}__].label}"></label>-->
<!--                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('customValues[__${itemStat.index}__].value')}"-->
<!--                        th:errors="*{customValues[__${itemStat.index}__].value}">Error</small>-->
                </div>

<!--                <div th:case="NUMBER" class="md-form form-group">-->
<!--                    <input type="number" th:id="'customValue' + ${i}" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}"-->
<!--                        class="form-control" th:errorclass="invalid" placeholder="Enter numbers only">-->
<!--                    <label th:for="'customValue' + ${i}" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">NAME</label>-->
<!--                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*{customValues[__${i}__].value}')}"-->
<!--                        th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>-->
<!--                </div>-->

<!--                <div th:case="YESNO" class="form-group md-form yes-no-input">-->
<!--                    <span class="label-multi" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">YES/NO</span>-->
<!--                    <div class="yes-no-check pb-2">-->
<!--                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline" th:each="b : ${allBooleanTypes}">-->
<!--                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio"-->
<!--                                   th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}" th:value="${b}" />-->
<!--                            <label class="form-check-label" th:for="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}"-->
<!--                                   th:text="#{${b==true ? 'myCompany.yes' : 'myCompany.no'}}">Wireframe</label>-->
<!--                        </div>-->
<!--                        <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*{customValues[__${i}__].value}')}"-->
<!--                               th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>-->
<!--                    </div>-->
<!--                </div>-->

<!--                <div th:case="PHONE" class="md-form form-group">-->
<!--                    <input type="text" th:id="'customValue' + ${i}" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}"-->
<!--                        class="form-control phone-text" th:errorclass="invalid" placeholder="###-###-####">-->
<!--                    <label th:for="'customValue' + ${i}" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">NAME</label>-->
<!--                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*{customValues[__${i}__].value}')}"-->
<!--                        th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>-->
<!--                </div>-->

<!--                <div th:case="DATE" class="md-form form-group">-->
<!--                    <input type="text" th:id="'customValue' + ${i}" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}"-->
<!--                        class="form-control child_dob_input_date" th:errorclass="invalid" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD">-->
<!--                    <label th:for="'customValue' + ${i}" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">NAME</label>-->
<!--                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*{customValues[__${i}__].value}')}"-->
<!--                           th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>-->
<!--                </div>-->

<!--                <div th:case="YEARMONTH" class="md-form form-group">-->
<!--                    <input type="text" th:id="'customValue' + ${i}" th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}"-->
<!--                        class="form-control child_dob_input_YM" th:errorclass="invalid" placeholder="YYYY-MM">-->
<!--                    <label th:for="'customValue' + ${i}" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">NAME</label>-->
<!--                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*{customValues[__${i}__].value}')}"-->
<!--                           th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>-->
<!--                </div>-->

<!--                <div th:case="ANY" class="form-group md-form">-->
<!--                    <textarea rows="1" type="text" th:name="'customFields.customField' + ${i}"-->
<!--                        th:id="'customValue' + ${i}" class="form-control custom-textarea"-->
<!--                        th:field="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}" placeholder="Enter any letters"-->
<!--                        th:errorclass="invalid"></textarea>-->
<!--                    <label th:for="'customValue' + ${i}" th:text="*{customValues[__${i}__].label}">NAME</label>-->
<!--                    <small class="text-danger" th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('*{customValues[__${i}__].value}')}"-->
<!--                           th:errors="*{customValues[__${i}__].value}">Error</small>-->
<!--                </div>-->

            </div>
            <!--</div>-->
        </div>

    </div> <!-- fragment -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have you solved? isn't some cache? have you seen directly in the database?

Comment: see the object final BindingResult bindingResult for any binding errors:
if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // errors processing
}

Comment: also, please share the complete html, where are you binding the customValues object using th:field="*{customValues}"???

Comment: @RhadamezGindriHercilio it isn't any cache, as I'm debugging in the `@PostMapping` method on the `@Controller` and the values on the `@ModelAttribute("card") @Valid final CardDTO editCardDTO` aren't being updated.

Comment: @ZeeshanArif there aren't any binding errors. The binding of `customValues` comes from the `th:object="${card}"` as the `CardDTO` has the `customValues` member.

Comment: @ZeeshanArif I have updated it with the full HTML

Comment: th:each="i: *{#numbers.sequence(0, customValues.size() - 1)}" th:if="*{customValues}"> don't iterate like this

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be with the HTTP POST request. Specifically its encoding.
See this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26503292/3461793

Assuming you do not have @SessionAttributes on your controller with the "card" and mixing your conversation id.

Comment: The controller is annotated with `@SessionAttributes({"card"})`

Comment: In that case, you probably provide "card" to model before even triggering the submitChildCardEdit method. Either with method level @ModelAttribute or in a method something like this `model.addAttribute("card", someCard);`. Otherwise you would encounter with an exception with message like this: "org.springframework.web.HttpSessionRequiredException: Expected session attribute 'card'". Please see [Session Attributes in Spring MVC](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-session-attributes#using-the-sessionattributes-annotation)